# How can I check for cin.fail() but still utilize ctrl+d to reach end of document?

Tags: c++, try-catch, cin, eof, ctrl

Using C++ on Linux terminal vi.

My first class assignment is to create an average from user input. Which I've accomplished, however to total the average we must use "ctrl+d" to reach the EOF. We must also prevent the program from crashing if the the user enters a non-numbers. The problem I'm having is everything I try to use to catch non-numbers ends up catching "ctrl+d" as well.

This is my current code. I've tried many variations of implementing the cin.fail() catch. I've also tried other methods of catching non-numbers, but I feel I must be missing something obvious, since this is my first coding class's first assignment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Please enter as many test scores as you want then use ctrl+d to 
  calculate the average.";

  double tot {0}, testNum {1};

  while (!cin.eof())
  {
    double input;

    cout << endl << "Enter Score" << testNum << ":";
    cin >> input;
    //need better alt can't use ctrl+d w/ this
    while (cin.fail())
    {
       cin.clear();
       cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
       cout <<endl << "Invalid entry. \nTest scores are graded numerically 
       and don't drop below 0. \nPlease type a positive number.";
       cout << " \nEnter Score " << testNum << ":";
       cin >> input;
    }
  tot += input;
  testNum++;
  }

double avg = tot / testNum;
cout << endl << "The average score is: " << avg;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Ctrl-D` as a signal to end input?  Why not just have the user enter a sentry value, like -1?  Or just ask the user up front how many scores they want to enter, and then stop reading after that many scores have actually been entered?

Comment: I know that would be much simpler but this is a class assignment and it specifies to use "ctrl+d" it also requires me to have the user prompted in that way. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: then you should talk to your instructor abouy how this should be implemented.

Comment: I intend to, but my instructor is out for two weeks. We have a sub and this is due Monday, so I've been trying to figure it out on my own. I'll keep trying. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a work around! I changed the initial while() to while(input >= 0) and used this code after cin >> input. Now it still allows CTRL+d to end the code and catches other characters so the program doesn't crash.

```
      if (!cin.eof())
  {
     while (cin.fail()) //using "ctrl+d" to reach eof doesn't work with this.
     {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << endl << "Invalid entry.";
        cout << "\nPlease enter Test Score not Letter Grade.";
        cout << endl << " \nEnter Score " << testNum << ":";
        cin >> input;
     }
  }
  else
  {
     break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant test `eof()` until after you attempt to read something and it goes past EOF.  So `while(eof())` is almost always wrong.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter as many test scores as you want then use Ctrl+D to calculate the average.";

    double totalScore = 0;
    int numScores = 0;

    do {
        double score;

        do {
            cout << endl << "Enter Score " << numScores+1 << ":";
            if (cin >> score)
                break;

            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << endl << "Invalid entry.";
        }
        while (true);

        if (cin.eof())
            break;

        if (score < 0)
        {
            cout << endl << "Test scores are graded numerically and don't drop below 0. \nPlease type a positive number.";
            continue;
        }

        totalScore += score;
        ++numScores;
    }
    while (true);

    if (numScores == 0)
        cout << endl << "No scores were entered.";
    else
    {
        double avg = totalScore / numScores;
        cout << endl << "The average score is: " << avg;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for all the help! I'm definitely going to use this as a reference and test it against my own.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding all of your code correctly I would like to check on one thing. I understand that the while(true) of (cin >> score) becomes false if a non-number is entered. But for the main do{}while (true) I'm not sure what triggers that false? Is it also non-numbers or is it simply that it isn't ever triggered because reaching eof ends the program?

Comment: I tried out your code, but hitting ctrl+d outputs invalid entry. I think it has the same problem as my original code.